# how to remove the square bracket that are leftover in list with python?

Tags: python, list

I have generated the results into the list like this

```
In[11]: a

Out[11]: [[[1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 6]],
         [[2, 4], [2, 6]],
         [[3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 6]],
         [[4]],
         [[5, 4]],
         [[6]]]
```

but I would like to remove the square brackets that are leftover resulting as this

```
[[1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 6],[2, 4], [2, 6],[3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 6],[4],[5, 4],[6]]
```

I have tried `sum(a,[])` to reduce 1 dimension but the result is shown as follows

```
[1, 3, 2, 4, 1, 3, 2, 6, 2, 4, 2, 6, 3, 2, 4, 3, 2, 6, 4, 5, 4, 6]
```

and tried np.squeeze(a) but the result is shown as follows

```
array([list([1, 3, 2, 4]), list([1, 3, 2, 6]), list([2, 4]), list([2, 6]),
       list([3, 2, 4]), list([3, 2, 6]), list([4]), list([5, 4]),
       list([6])], dtype=object)
```

any suggestions for aggregating this kind of list?

thank you in advance

Comment: `sum(a,[])` worked on my machine. [check](https://repl.it/repls/ConsciousArtisticKeys).

Comment: Yes. In my machine too. Not sure why it didn't work in user's machine.

Comment: i don't know the problem with this issue too. thank you for your comment!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this below :

```
    a = [[[1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 6]],
         [[2, 4], [2, 6]],
         [[3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 6]],
         [[4]],
         [[5, 4]],
         [[6]]]
    output = [elem for output_list in a for elem in output_list]
    print(output)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
a = [[[1, 3, 2, 4], [1, 3, 2, 6]],
     [[2, 4], [2, 6]],
     [[3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 6]],
     [[4]],
     [[5, 4]],
     [[6]]]

fl = []
for i in a:
    for j in i:
        fl.append(j)

print fl
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
str(a).replace('[[','[').replace(']]',']')
```